# IndexedDB open DB request weird behavior

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have an app (questionnaire)  that uses indexedDB. 
We have one database and several stores in it.

Stores have data already stored in them.

At some point a dashboard html file is loaded. In this file I am calling couple of functions:

```
function init(){
            adjustUsedScreenHeight();
            db_init();
            setInstitutionInstRow();
            loadRecommendations();
            loadResultsFromDB();
            fillEvaluations();
            document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, function(e) {console.log(e);}); 
        }
```

The init() function is called on body onLoad.

setInstitutionInstRow() looks like these:

```
 function setInstitutionInstRow(localId){
//localId = 10;
if (localId == undefined){
    console.log("Localid underfined: ");
    //open db, open objectstore;
    var request = indexedDB.open("kcapp_db", "1.0");

    request.onsuccess = function() {
        var db = request.result;    
        var tx = db.transaction ("LOCALINSTITUTIONS", "readonly");
        var store = tx.objectStore("LOCALINSTITUTIONS");

        tx.oncomplete = function(){
            db.close();
        }
        tx.onerror = function(){
            console.log("Transaction error on setInstInstRow");
        }

        var cursor = store.openCursor();
        cursor.onsuccess= function () {
            var match = cursor.result;
            console.log ("Retrieved item: " + match.value.instid);
            //  alert("Added new data");
            if (match){
                setInstituionInstRow(match.value.instid);
                console.log("Got localid: " + math.value.instid);
            }
            else
                console.log("localinsid: it is empty " );
        };

        cursor.onerror = function () {
            console.log("Error: " + item.result.errorCode);
        }

    }

    request.onerror = function () {
        console.log("Error: " + request.result.errorCode );
    }

    request.oncomplete = function (){
        console.log("The transaction is done: setInstitutionRow()");
    }

    request.onupgradeneeded = function (){
        console.log("Upgrade needed ...");
    }

    request.onblocked = function(){
        console.log("DB is Blocked ...");
    }


} else {
    instid = localId;
    var now = new Date();
    //console.log("["+now.getTime()+"]setInstituionInstRow - instid set to "+localId);
    //open db, open objectstore;
    var request = indexedDB.open("kcapp_db", "1.0");

    request.onsuccess = function() {
        var db = this.result;   
        var tx = db.transaction ("INSTITUTIONS", "readonly");
        var store = tx.objectStore("INSTITUTIONS");

        var item = store.get(localId);
        console.log(item);

        item.onsuccess= function () {
            console.log ("Retrieved item: ");
            if (item.length > 0)
                var lInstitution = item.result.value;
                kitaDisplayValue = lInstitution.krippe;     
            };

        item.onerror = function () {
            console.log("Error: " + item.result.errorCode);
        }

    }


    request.onerror = function () {
        console.log("Error: " + request.result.errorCode );
    }


}
```

Now the problem is,

```
var request = indexedDB.open("kcapp_db", "1.0");
```

the above request is never getting into any onsuccess, oncomplete, onerror states. I debugged with Chrome tools, it never getting into any above states.

Accordingly I am not getting any data from transactions.

And there are no errors in Chrome console.

And here is the request value from Chrome dev:

[image]

From above image the readyState: done , which means it should fire an event (success, error, blocked etc). But it is not going into any of them.

I am looking into it, and still can not figure out why it is not working.

Have to mention that the other functions from init() is behaving the same way.

Looking forward to get some help.

Comment: I am not really going further with this one. I checked all the suggestions, but still the same behavior, never firing any events. Still looking for some help.

Comment: It would be immensely helpful if you can link to a jsbin with your code that shows the issue. It doesn't have to be (and shouldn't be) your full code, just the minimum that demonstrates the unexpected behavior.

Comment: Hi. I can not link it, since I do not have it in accessible in internet. Do you know any places (good ones) to place projects, that works good with linking in stackoverflow?

Comment: any luck on your question? in my case indexedDB do not work on different computers on chrome. on edge/firefox works as expected

Answer (score 1):

You may be using an invalid version parameter to the open function. Try `indexedDB.open('kcapp_db', 1);` instead.

Comment: I tried with integer, it is not working. For other functions of mine it is working fine with string version.

Comment: It should never work with strings unless there is some implicit type coercion occurring.  A followup question is whether you are using any type of indexedDB library/shim? Try not using it.

Comment: I am using pure indexedDB without any shim/library. Chrome sees string "1.0" as 1 (integer). From above picture the readyState of request is "done". Does it mean it is finished?

Comment: Sorry but I do not know enough about devtools to answer that. I would listen to dgrogan, he is one of the developers of Chrome's indexedDB.

Answer (score 1):

1. Like Josh said, your version parameter should be an integer, not a string.
2. Your request object can get 4 events in response to the open request: `success`, `error`, `upgradeneeded`, or `blocked`. Add event listeners for all of those (e.g. `request.onblocked = ...`) and see which one is getting fired.

Comment: I added other event listeners, it is weird, none of them are fired. It is just not going into any of them. Any idea what is wrong there?

Comment: Have a look also above image. Added the image of request state information from Chrome dev tools. It is weird all them are null.

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem but only with the "onupgradeneeded" event. I fixed it changing the name of the "open" function. At the begining I had a very long name; I changed it for a short one and start working. I don't know if this is the real problem but it was solved at that moment.

My code:

```
if (this.isSupported) {
            this.openRequest = indexedDB.open("OrdenesMant", 1);

            /**
             * Creación de la base de datos con tablas y claves primarias
             */ 
            this.openRequest.onupgradeneeded = function(oEvent) {
...
```

Hope it works for you as well.